# Data not getting deleted from Firebase when device time becomes equal to the time stored on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, date-format, android-calendar

I have given option to the user to choose a time till when his content should be on the database and after this time the content should get deleted.

I have stored the chosen time in this format: `4:30 PM` and then I'm retrieving it and comparing with the device time. If the device time becomes equal to the time chosen by the user, the content should get deleted from `FirebaseDatabase`.

I'm using this code for comparing fetched time and device time:

```
DateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        final String time = currentTime.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        if (time.matches(holder.availableFor.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), time, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.firebaseDatabase.child(itemID).setValue(null);
            holder.geoFireReference.child(itemID).setValue(null);
        }
```

where `holder.availableFor.getText().toString()` is the time in format `4:30 PM` fetched from the database and the `time` is the time of the device in the same format.

The problem is that suppose current time is `6:15 PM` and for testing I have chosen the time at which this content should get deleted to be `6:18 PM`, I keep the app open and waits for the content to get deleted and disappear as soon as device time gets to `6:18 PM`, but this doen't happen and the content remains there instead of getting deleted. Another thing I noticed is that if I close the app and open it at `6:18 PM`, then the content gets deleted and disappear.

Please let me know what's going wrong here and how can I delete a content successfully from he database as soon as the device time becomes equal to the time chosen by the user.

P.S.: This all code is in a model class which extends `AbstractItem<>`.

Comment: Are you showing data in listview or RecylerView if yes then you have to notify ur UI. I think your data is deleted but couldn't update on UI.